# Cannot register duplicate name error when using unique name in a Page namescope in WPF app

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF. I wish to simply display a `<Page>` (`Page1.xaml`) within `MainWindow.xaml` (a Metro UI MetroWindow component). I am able to display it with a `<Frame>` object placed in `MainWindow.xaml`. I'd also like to populate DataGrid objects and other components with codebehind, but the second I add a `Name=` or `x:Name=` to anything within `Page1.xaml`, I get this error:  `"Could not register named object. Cannot register duplicate name 'SuperUniqueName' in this scope."`

I have looked at every possible related post and found nothing that fixed the problem. I also tried making the codebehind for the Page1 (`Page1.xaml.cs`) use private, which gave a different error I was unable to solve. 
I have also successfully added names to elements (without crashing, and able to bind data) within MainWindow.xaml, but not when adding to Page1.xaml.

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="TumorManager2GUI.MainWindow"
                        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TumorManager2GUI"
                        mc:Ignorable="d"
                        Height="810"
                        Width="1440">

    <Grid>
        <Frame 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
            Source="/;component/Page1.xaml"/>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```c
/// default "using" hidden
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace TumorManager2GUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml

```xml
<Page x:Class="TumorManager2GUI.Page1"
      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TumorManager2GUI"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Title="Page1">

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="SuperUniqueName" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```c
/// default "using" hidden
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace TumorManager2GUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page1
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

What i expect is there to be no crash when adding Names to elements within , so i can set bindings. Instead, I get the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a spurious error created because you used the wrong path in your frame.

Change your Frame source to:

```
Source="Page1.xaml"/>
```

I also recommend you use usercontrols rather than pages.

Look into MVVM and viewmodel first navigation.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-do-not-use-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it! The source was auto-written because I had selected the Page component within the properties panel, and I didn't know I could rewrite it as such. And I definitely will look into using contentcontrol/usercontrol combo instead.