# WPF clickonce issue on azure devops

Tags: wpf, azure-devops, clickonce, .net-4.8

I have a runtime error when I published a .NetFramework WPF app from an azure devops pipeline.

The error is the following :

```
2023-01-09 16:26:01,230 [1] ERROR XXX.Logging.Log - 'Impossible d'inscrire l'objet nommé. Impossible d'inscrire le nom dupliqué 'tbLogin' dans cette portée.' numéro de ligne '26' et position de ligne '14'.
Impossible d'inscrire le nom dupliqué 'tbLogin' dans cette portée.
Data :System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
StackTrace:
   à System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   à System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   à System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   à System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   à System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   à MS.Internal.AppModel.AppModelKnownContentFactory.BamlConverter(Stream stream, Uri baseUri, Boolean canUseTopLevelBrowser, Boolean sandboxExternalContent, Boolean allowAsync, Boolean isJournalNavigation, XamlReader& asyncObjectConverter)
   à MS.Internal.AppModel.MimeObjectFactory.GetObjectAndCloseStream(Stream s, ContentType contentType, Uri baseUri, Boolean canUseTopLevelBrowser, Boolean sandboxExternalContent, Boolean allowAsync, Boolean isJournalNavigation, XamlReader& asyncObjectConverter)
   à System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.GetObjectFromResponse(WebRequest request, WebResponse response, Uri destinationUri, Object navState)
   à System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.DoNavigate(Uri source, NavigationMode f, Object navState)
   à System.Windows.Navigation.NavigateQueueItem.Dispatch(Object obj)
   à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   à MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   à MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   à MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   à MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   à System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   à System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   à Apps.XXX.BO.WPF.App.Main()
Source:
PresentationFramework
TargetSite:
Void RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
BaseException:
System.ArgumentException: Impossible d'inscrire le nom dupliqué 'tbLogin' dans cette portée.
   à System.Xaml.NameScope.RegisterName(String name, Object scopedElement)
   à System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.RegisterName(ObjectWriterContext ctx, String name, Object inst, XamlType xamlType, INameScope nameScope, INameScope parentNameScope, Boolean isRoot)
```

I don't have this runtime error when I publish on my computer from Visual Studio.

The publish task on the pipeline is defined as :

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: "Build solution with ClickOnce Deploy"
  inputs:
    solution: '**/$(ProjectName).csproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArguments: '/target:Publish /p:ApplicationVersion=$(AssemblyVersion) /p:PublishDir="$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Publish" /p:ProductName="$(ProductName)" /p:InstallUrl="$(blobStorageUrl)$(Configuration)/" /p:PublishUrl=$(blobStorageUrl)'
```

Do any of you have any idea what is causing the problem?

Thanks,

Note : `tbLogin` is defined only once in the application.

**Update**

Problem solved.

I follow this instructions : [Cannot register duplicate name error when using unique name in a Page namescope in WPF app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931601/cannot-register-duplicate-name-error-when-using-unique-name-in-a-page-namescope)

On the MainWindow, I had a frame describe as follow :

```
<Frame x:Name="FrmMain" Grid.Row="1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="/<XXX>;component/Views/LoginView.xaml" />
```

I replace it by :

```
<Frame x:Name="FrmMain" Grid.Row="1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="LoginView.xaml" />
```

And everything work as expected after my devops publish.

Comment: You might want to translate that error message to english in your question. google says register the duplicate name 'tbLogin' in this scope